# Running SQL query against Azure redis cache

Tags: azure, caching, redis, azure-caching

I have a table in database which is named `Country` table. I want to put this table data on Azure redis cache. This table data will change once a week or month so, I will update cache once a week. I wanted to know is there any way which allow me to run SQL query on this cached data ?. For example: If i want to run `SELECT * FROM country WHERE id = 1;` or `SELECT * FROM country WHERE countryName = 'somename';`  or `SELECT * FROM country WHERE id=1 OR countryName='somename';`. Please let me know if there is any way to do this.

Comment: Did you check https://redisearch.io? With the RediSearch module you can query the data in Redis

Comment: does it works with azure redis cache ? I'm new to this please help me. Thanks.

Comment: It works with Azure Cache Enterprise layer or you can get on Redis Labs cloud for Azure

Comment: can you please give me any link where to find sample for this, if you have reference please.

Comment: You can refer to this in github. https://github.com/siscia/rediSQL/

Comment: ok thanks the reference

Comment: This is a nice SQL based module for Redis but I was talking about https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/overview/ and https://redislabs.com/cloud-partners/microsoft-azure/

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: I couldn't find solution which fits my problem so, dropped this idea.